# Edit Single HTML Code to Change Multiple Pages

Tags: html, css, edit, shortcut

I'm putting together an HTML/CSS webpage, with a navigation bar that is displayed on each page. I'm hoping to find a way that I can make a single edit on a certain part of this  code, so that it makes changes on every page; rather than making the changes to each page alone.

Thanks,
DW

Comment: And you've tried what so far?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use php for this

Save your navigation as an include and insert it on each page

Each time edit the navigation file it will show the changes on each page where the navigation is inserted

Answer (score 0):

One way that you could achieve your aim (assuming you are using a Windows OS) is by using 'Dynamic Web Templates'. Microsoft Expression is a free HTML editor that includes this functionality.
You create an outline web page to be used as the basis for other pages and then save this as a template. In your case, this would contain the navigation bar.
Then, when you create a new HTML page, you insert the template and can then add content that is unique to each page.
Whenever you then make a change to anything in the template and save it, every one of the other (linked) pages is automatically updated.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you will need to use some sort of [Server Side Include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html). This may or may not take a slight bit of configuration to enable depending on your setup.

If your site truly is pure html, although pain to manage, it might be flat-out easiest to just have it on every page.

Otherwise, a (better) option would be to use php or some other programming language to handle this.